# Nested modules import from sibling directory python

Tags: python, module

I know this has been asked before but I still can't wrap my head around how this works. I'm trying to do a pretty simple thing which should intuitively work but doesn't, please help me what I'm doing wrong. I have a folder structure like this:

```
src/
    foo/
       __init__.py
       foo.py
    bar/
       __init__.py
       bar.py
       xyz.py
```

I'm trying to import the `XYZ` class in `xyz.py` from within `foo.py`. If I write

```
from bar.xyz import XYZ
```

I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bar'
```

But if I write

```
from ..bar.xyz import XYZ
```

I get

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I also tried doing

```
from src.bar.xyz import XYZ
```

But again I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

I try adding `__init__.py` in `src/` but that also results in the same error. I know I can call `sys.add` or something and the parent path before importing but that really seems like an hack which I don't want to do. What am I missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: I had almost the exact same problem with one of my projects, and for me the solution was to make the entire project "installable" and use relative imports for everything, but I did that also because it was large and harder to solve the issue without doing so. In your case, your import will simply work if you run the foo as a module like this: `python -m foo.foo`